# Sklearn error when trying to call a new classifier - Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nltk

Whenever I try to call a new classifier I get the same error...

Here's my code:

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

BernoulliNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB())
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\scikitlearn.py", line 69, in __init__
self._encoder = LabelEncoder()
NameError: name 'LabelEncoder' is not defined
```

When I look at the documentation that's exactly how it should be called (see http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html)

Plus, it works on Python 2.7.

NB: I tried with the multinomial naive bayes, the support vector machines and many other algos, it returns the same error.

Comment: What does `from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder` return from your python 3.4 environment? You probably don't have your environment properly set up. See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py#L41

Comment: @dukebody it imports normally, I already tried this..

Comment: @Charles: Do you have Numpy, Scipy, Scikit-learn in Python3 packages? If not install it using PIP3.

Comment: @ravi yes, i have all these packages

Comment: @Charles I have the same issue - did you find a resolution?

Comment: @SHC Unfortunately no... If you find a solution please let me know lol, at the moment I switched to Python 2.7

Comment: Try uninstalling the sklearn or better yet create a new virtual environment and install fresh packages!

Comment: I had the same error with python 3.6.9 while I was inside of the python idle, I solved with just exiting and entering again to the python idle

Answer (score 4):

try restarting the kernel, worked for me